# Can I ask a question about guidance for looking for a PhD?

Tags: discussion

I have an engineering background but I want to do a Ph.D. in psychology. Can I ask a question about this giving the details?

Comment: There are lots of existing questions on "if I have a degree in ____ can I apply for a PhD in _____" - I'd look through those before posting any question of your own. They get pretty dull and uninteresting and usually end up depending a lot on individual factors so many get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have background X and want a PhD in Y" questions are both fairly common here, and often get closed because they depend on individual factors we can't know - like how receptive a particular lab or labs would be to someone with that background, etc.

If you want advice, I'd strongly suggest you refine your questions more to things that are *specific* and that can be answered generally (at least within a field).